# In Home Assistant is it possible to make a button to cast/mirror audio to Google Home

Tags: google-home, home-assistant

Is it possible to make a button in home assistant that will cast my device's audio similar to the "Cast my audio" button in google home. I want this for apps that don't have their own cast button (like Audible).

[image]

Comment: please don't ask questions that have a simple yes/no answer ... it wastes everyone's time who is guessing what you have tried and what problems you faced and what you are actually wanting to know